# Can I use 10666 ram with a motherboard that says its ram standard is 1333?

Tags: memory, motherboard

Just bought a dual pack of DDR3 1333 (PC3 10666) G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 8GB and want to put it in a ASUS P8H61-I (REV 3.0) LGA 1155, will this work without any problems?

Is it okay to use both of them together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the G.Skill Ripjaw memory is on the ASUS motherboard's approved memory list.

BTW "DDR3 1333" is equivalent to "PC3 10666".